# Placing namespaces with css

Tags: css, namespaces

I am trying to add to prevent twitterbootstrap from conflicting with some previous other css files, Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I want everything to be wrapped with a .tbwrap class.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the FAQ before posting questions. People here will gladly help, but with specific questions. Yours is a little vague. If you can edit it include a specific question, and show what you've tried/looked into, we can help.

Comment: If you use PHP you can have a look at this class: http://code.google.com/p/aframework/source/browse/trunk/aFramework/Lib/CSSSelectorPrefixer.php?r=1298. And you use it like: `CSSSelectorPrefixer::prefixSelectors($codeHere, '.tbwrap ')`

Comment: Sorry guys, I didnt know how to explain it in further detail to be honest. @powerbuoy thanks for this. Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to use is LESS.

an example from [LESS homepage](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage)

```
  #header {
      h1 {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      p { font-size: 12px;
        a { text-decoration: none;
          &:hover { border-width: 1px }
        }
      }
    }
```

/* Compiled CSS */

```
#header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header p a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header p a:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

1. Wrap all of your css in .tbwrap - this will be your LESS file.
2. Use an online complier such as [Winless](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) to convert LESS into CSS

Comment: IIRC, doesn't Bootstrap use LESS anyway?

Comment: This is true but the example needn't be using twitterbootstrap to work.

Comment: But the OP is using Bootstrap, so why go through the efforts of using LESS alongside LESS?